# How to use alpha Textures in Blender

Tags: texturing, transparency

Is it possible to use Alpha texture in Blender. If yes then how can i use it. A guy made this using alpha Texture in Substance painter.

[image]

So is it possible to make ornamental design using Alpha texture with the reference given above image. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: I am confused by your reference to Alpha and Alpha brush. If the question is how can I texture an object with embossed patterns as in the reference image, then yes you can. The are various options, Bump being the easiest.

Comment: @rob sorry its alpha texture not brush